# Xamarin Dropbox Core Api Android v2 support

Tags: c#, xamarin, dropbox

I'm having problems using the Xamarin Dropbox Core API for Android. 
https://components.xamarin.com/view/dropboxcoreapiandroid
We have an application that was working for years and stopped on September 28th, 2017 when Dropbox stopped supporting their Core API v1.  We thought we were up to date and even tried the sample code that is supplied by Xamarin 
but that also crashes with the message "v1_retired" buried in the error message.  The app will successfully authorize and links using OAuth2 to an account but will crash when a call to .MetaData or any other call after that.  Does the Xamarin API need to be updated?   Doesn't the fact that it uses OAuth2 indicate that is using Dropbox's Core API v2?  Is there an alternative that is available for C#?  I'm sure others are having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the Xamarin API need to be updated?

Yes, if you're getting the `v1_retired` error, it indicates you're using API v1 and need to update to API v2. If you need more time to migrate your app to API v2, we can offer an extension for access to API v1. To request that, please [open an API ticket](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact) with the relevant app key(s).

> Doesn't the fact that it uses OAuth2 indicate that is using Dropbox's Core API v2?

No, OAuth version is not the same as the API version. For reference, Dropbox API v1 supported both OAuth 1 and OAuth 2, whereas Dropbox API v2 only supports OAuth 2.

> Is there an alternative that is available for C#?

Dropbox doesn't offer an official API v2 SDK for Xamarin, but there are some third party libraries listed on [the Community SDKs page](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/communitysdks).

Comment: I feel like it's really silly Dropbox doesn't offer a Xamarin SDK, it's not that much work to do it (for a company like DropBox) yet it would help devs immensely, cloud rail is kinda limited in what you are allowed to do without paying an obscene amount of money, which in turn makes me just not want to integrate Dropbox in my app at all.